# the specified network password is not correct Exception in the X509Certificate2Collection.Import()

Tags: c#

I have a secret of a certificate . And I try to recreate a certificate

```
certValue = "MXKMAKM....."

509Certificate2Collection exportedCertCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            exportedCertCollection.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(certValue));
```

It generate an exception in the `exportedCertCollection.Import()` part .

> Exception : the specified network password is not correct .

I am wondering does it mean I need to have a password for this secrete?  Actually it shouldn't. Can anyone share any highlights?

Comment: Import requires the exact bytes from the certificate.  Convert.FromBase64String alters the bytes.  Instead use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string);  In your case the string is certValue.

Comment: I have tried this . There is "An error occurred during encode or decode operation.\r\n"}

Comment: Just use '\r' instead of '\r\n'  You are getting error because of the '\n'.  You are correctly processing the line which ends in '\r' and then getting an error sending just '\n'.